# Discord.py bot using 300+ mb of ram

Tags: discord, discord.py

About two months ago my discord.py bot suddenly started using 300mb+ of ram out of nowhere. I am not sure what triggered this. This happens when I use my host and also when I self-host. I have tried tagging out all my cogs except for the main bot.py file, and it was still taking up tons of ram. I have the presence intent and server member intent enabled, my bot is in 31 servers, and has 11 cogs. Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to help, but I honestly couldn't say for sure. You could've changed settings, or maybe you're caching all the data, it could've even been affected by an update.

If you want to find out the cause to this I would suggest you try stripping your bot to the bare essentials (just running the token), and then slowly add in more cogs to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: I removed all my cogs, so I only had the main bot.py file left, and it still didn't work. I am a bit confused with all this.

Comment: Yes, it happens wherever I run it, both my pc and my host.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what else to suggest

Comment: That's totally fine! If anyone else has an answer, feel free to tell me :)